# Windows Mobile to Zebra Printer over WLAN (ad hoc)

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, wifi, zebra-printers

I have an Intermec (CN3) Windows Mobile 5.0 device and a Zebra P4T printer.

The printer does not have blue tooth.

But the printer does have wireless capabilities that can be configured from a PC.  http://j.imagehost.org/0665/printer_network_config.png

The working environment does not have a wireless network that we can take advantage of.

We are writing a .NET Compact Framework application that will run on the Intermec device and print to the Zebra printer over a wireless connection.

What device configurations should allow us to do this?

What kind of network-establishing code will my application need to connect to the printer?

I do not have a lot of experience with networking.  I can look up the SDKs and APIs that Intermec and Windows Mobile provides, but I am not sure what I am looking for.
If you can even provide pseudo-code of the overall plan on how to establish this kind of connection, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Zebra provides a WinMobile SDK](http://www.zebra.com/sdk)  for printing from a WinMobile device to a zebra printer. There is good documentation provided, and several demo apps which give you all the code you need to connect to a Zebra Printer over TCP, and send/receive data from your printer

Comment: But only seems to work with VS 2008, whereas I need a VS 2003 solution.