# How to print to a MZ220 printer from .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: printing, compact-framework, zebra-printers

I am developing a app with .NET Compact Framework for a [Motorola MC2180](http://www.windowsfordevices.com/c/a/News/Motorola-MC2180-device-profile/).

This app needs to print to a [Zebra MZ 220 printer](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/printers/printer-type/mobile/mz-series.html).

How can you print from the .NET Compact Framework, and customize it for a particular printer?

Answer (score 1):

See my [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3947541/64238)  Zebra provides an SDK for winMobile